# How to make a C# Windows Form Application fit to the screen

Tags: c#, forms, resize

I'm very new to coding and was wondering about a few things to do with my project.

I am currently designing a quiz for a school project, and I was wondering how I could get each form to fit to the user's screen, whilst making the buttons, textboxes, and picture boxes look like they should be where they are.

I am wording this question very badly but I don't know how else to put it. Basically, I am just searching for a way to make my form (with buttons, textboxes, pictureboxes) fit to any monitor.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Simply Use :
FormName.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to anchor and dock your controls as appropriate. Here's a good article to get you started: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

where this is your form's name , This code will make your form full screen

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Form.WindowState property to FormWindowState.Maximized :)